# Selenium - Able to get the list of Webelements rendered & displayed in a Web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium

I am on the look out for a solution to get only the web elements which is displayed on a web page.
For example, for the web page https://login.yahoo.com/, there is only a few web elements which are rendered to the browser ( 1 input box, 7 links, 1 button etc )

When I try to get only these web elements, all I am getting is a large number of web elements in my collection.

For example, I am getting the select web element when I query the HTML

```
<select type="select" name="countryCodeIntl" aria-required="true" role="combobox" aria-multiline="false" aria-labelledby="country-code-lbl-aria" disabled="">
    <option role="option" data-code="+93" value="AF">Afghanistan ‪(+93)‬</option>       
</select>
```

This Select element is not available in the web page. Not sure how to ignore this web element while querying the DOM

I tried the following approaches

```
 1. Displayed==true ( Selenium funcitonality )

 2. IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            Boolean elementVisible = (Boolean)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].offsetWidth > 0", myCurElement);
            Boolean elementVisible1 = (Boolean)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].offsetHeight > 0", myCurElement);
            Boolean elementVisible2 = (Boolean)js.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].getClientRects().length > 0", myCurElement);
            if (elementVisible ==true&& elementVisible1== true && elementVisible2 == true)
            {}
```

Both the above approaches returns elements which are invisible in the web page.

Any pointers on how to get only the HTML webelements which are visible to human eye in the browser? Can this be done using javascript?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: My output on chrome is different `x = $$("[name='countryCodeIntl']")[0]
<select type=​"select" name=​"countryCodeIntl" aria-required=​"true" role=​"combobox" aria-multiline=​"false" aria-labelledby=​"country-code-lbl-aria" disabled>​…​</select>​
x.getClientRects()
ClientRectList {length: 0}`

Comment: What is your exact Business Requirement? What are the manual steps you are trying to automate? can you share your research with us?

Comment: @TarunLalwani - Thanks. I surprised as all the conditions returns true. Anyways, I used the following code and worked    ' string displayproperty=myCurElement.GetCssValue("display");
                string visibleproperty = myCurElement.GetCssValue("visibility");

Comment: @DebanjanB - Thanks for your comment. I am working on a framework whose purpose is to create test flows from a web page. Hopefully all goes well. Thanks again

Comment: A requirement `to create test flows from a web page` is too big as a question on Stackoverflow.com to be Answered.

Comment: @DebanjanB - Thanks for your answer and comments and accepting your answer as it speak volume for the above said use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to `to get only the web elements which is displayed on a web page` doesn't justifies to me as a valid **`Business Case`**. A typical **`Testcase`** may want you to verify if a particular element (Button, Text, etc) is `displayed` or not.

As you mentioned `for the web page https://login.yahoo.com/, there is only a few web elements which are rendered to the browser ( 1 input box, 7 links, 1 button etc )`. Yes you saw it right as a **`End User`**. Here you missed out the fact that those ( 1 input box, 7 links, 1 button etc ) are with `property` **`visible`** set to `value` **`true`**. Hence you see them when you access the **`URL`**.

Next when you `try to get only these web elements, all I am getting is a large number of web elements in my collection` because of different reasons:

1. To find/search particular element/elements you need to take help of locators (either `id`, `name`, `linkText`, `css`, `xpath`). All these locators are unique for each and every element present on the `HTML DOM`. So if you are trying to use `xpath` or `css` ensure that the locators you constructed identifies a unique element (unique set of elements) on the `HTML DOM`.
2. All the elements on the `HTML DOM` necessarily doesn't shows up on the Website. That's because, some elements are kept hidden so they are not displayed on the Web page to restrict the `End Users` to perform any actions on them. These elements though not visible in the Website but they do exists as **`Hidden Elements`**

### Conclusion:

So `When I try to get only these web elements` consider identifying each element through respective locator which identifies the element uniquely on the `HTML DOM`. Once identified, you can perform any desired action (`sendKey()`, `click()`, etc) on them till they are attached to the `HTML DOM`